# Move last n lines of a text file to the top with Bash

Tags: bash, sed, command

How can I move last n lines of a text file to the top without knowing number of lines of the file? Is it possible to achieve this with single command line (with `sed` for example)?

From:

```
...
a
b
c
d
```

To:

```
a
b
c
d
...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 5):

### Updated 2021:

Using vim's ex mode is even simpler: (inspired by [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26920))

```
vim -        -esc '$-3,$m0|%p|q!' --not-a-term  # when processing a pipe
vim file.txt -esc '$-3,$m0|%p|q!' --not-a-term  # when processing a file to stdout
vim file.txt -esc '$-3,$m0|wq'    --not-a-term  # when editing a file inline
```

This will move last 4 lines (last line + 3 lines before the last line) to top. Change `3` to your desired number.

A MWE:

```
seq 10 | vim - '-esc$-3,$m0|%p|q!' --not-a-term
```

Output:

```
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

---

### Updated 2020:

You may find it hard if the input source is from pipe. In this case, you can use

```sh
awk '{a[NR-1]=$0}END{for(i=0;i<NR;++i)print(a[(i-4+NR)%NR])}'
```

This will store all lines in memory (which may be an issue) and then output them. Change `4` in the command to see different results.

---

Display the last n lines and then display the rest:

```
tail -n 4 file; head -n -4 file
```

From `man head`:

> -n, --lines=[-]NUM
>
> print  the  first  NUM  lines  instead of the first 10; with the leading '-', print all but the last NUM lines of each file

`tail -n 4` will display the last 4 lines of a file.

If you wish to pipe this data, you need to put them together like this:

```
( tail -n 4 file; head -n -4 file ) | wc
```

---

Or maybe you can use vim to edit file inline:

```
vim +'$-3,$m0' +'wq' file
```

The `+` option for vim will run the (Ex) command following it. `$-3,$m0` means move lines between 3 lines above the last line and the last line to the beginning of the file. Note that there should be no space between `+` and the command.

---

Or using commands in vim normal mode:

```
vim +'norm G3kdGggPZZ' file
```

`G` go to file end; `3k` move up 3 lines; `dG` deletes to file end; `gg` go to file top; `P` pastes the deleted lines before this line; `ZZ` saves and quits.

Comment: Three for the price of one - can't be bad!

Comment: The head/tail solution should be the fastest, and use less memory.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!H;1h;$!d;G' file
```

Append every line but the last to the [hold space](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Execution-Cycle) and then append the hold space to the the last line.

Answer (score 0):

It is trivial to do with `ed`

Move the last `30` lines on top of the file.

```
printf '%s\n' '30,$m0' ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

Move 10 to 50 lines on top of the file.

```
printf '%s\n' '10,50m0' ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

Move 1 to 10 to the last line/buffer.

```
printf '%s\n' '1,10m$' ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

Move 40 to 80 at the last line/buffer

```
printf '%s\n' '40,80m$' ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

- Line address `0` is the first and `m` means move
- `$` is the last line of the buffer/file.
- Change `Q` to `w` to actually edit the `file.txt`